# Help with part of the proof of Fubini's Theorem (for product spaces).

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Apologies in advance for the length of the question, it simply involves a lot of notation. Thanks in advance to anyone who will read through!

**Some exposition:** Suppose $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$
 and $\left(Y,\mathcal{G},\nu\right)$
  are $\sigma-\mbox{finite}$
  measure spaces, I denote the $\sigma$
 -algebra on the product $X\times Y$
  by $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G}$
 . given $Q\in\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G}$
  for each $x\in X$
  and $y\in Y$
  define: $$Q_{x}:=\left\{ y\in Y\,|\,\left(x,y\right)\in Q\right\} \qquad Q_{y}:=\left\{ x\in X\,|\,\left(x,y\right)\in Q\right\} 
 $$ 
 Given $Q\in\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G}$
 define $\varphi\left(x\right)=\nu\left(Q_{x}\right)$
  and $\psi\left(y\right)=\mu\left(Q_{y}\right)$
 . I've shown that for all $Q\in\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G}$ 
  these functions are measurable and that $\int_{X}\varphi\left(x\right)d\mu\left(x\right)=\int_{Y}\psi\left(y\right)d\nu\left(y\right)$. I mention this since it might be useful for my actual question.

**The Question** Suppose that $f:X\times Y\to\left[0,\infty\right]$
  is a $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G}$
 -measurable function and $\left\{ f_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$
  is a monotonically increasing sequence of simple measurable functions such that $f_{n}\uparrow f$. Given $x\in X$
  and $y\in Y$
 denote $f_{x}\left(y\right)=f\left(x,y\right)$
  and similarly $f_{y}\left(x\right)=f\left(x,y\right)$. From the measurability of $f_{n},f$
  it follows that $\left(f_{n}\right)_{y},f_{y}$
  are $\mathcal{F}$
 -measurable for all $y\in Y$
  and $\left(f_{n}\right)_{x},f_{x}$
  are $\mathcal{G}$
 -measurable for all $x\in X$. Now define for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$: $$\varphi_{n}\left(x\right)=\int\limits _{Y}\left(f_{n}\right)_{x}\left(y\right)d\nu\left(y\right)\quad\psi_{n}\left(y\right):=\int\limits _{X}\left(f_{n}\right)_{y}\left(x\right)d\mu\left(x\right)$$
 Also define: $$\varphi\left(x\right)=\int\limits _{Y}\left(f\right)_{x}\left(y\right)d\nu\left(y\right)\quad\psi\left(y\right):=\int\limits _{X}\left(f\right)_{y}\left(x\right)d\mu\left(x\right)$$
 Since $f_{n}\uparrow f$
  we got that $\left(f_{n}\right)_{x}\uparrow f_{x}$
  and $\left(f_{n}\right)_{y}\uparrow f_{y}$
  and thus from the monotone convergence theorem we got that $\varphi_{n}\uparrow\varphi$
  and $\psi_{n}\uparrow\psi$
  (these are also monotonic increasing sequences since $f_{n}$
  are non-negative). Now I want to use the monotone convergence theorem again to deduce that: $$\int_{X}\left(\int\limits _{Y}f_{x}\left(y\right)d\nu\left(y\right)\right)\mu\left(x\right)=\int_{X}\varphi\left(x\right)d\mu\left(x\right)\overbrace{=}^{\mbox{M.C}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\limits _{X}\varphi_{n}\left(x\right)d\mu\left(x\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\limits _{X}\left(\int\limits _{Y}\left(f_{n}\right)_{x}\left(y\right)d\nu\left(y\right)\right)d\mu\left(x\right)$$
$$\int_{Y}\left(\int\limits _{X}f_{y}\left(x\right)d\mu\left(x\right)\right)\nu\left(y\right)=\int_{Y}\psi\left(y\right)d\nu\left(y\right)\overbrace{=}^{\mbox{M.C}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\limits _{Y}\psi_{n}\left(y\right)d\nu\left(y\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\limits _{Y}\left(\int\limits _{X}\left(f_{n}\right)_{y}\left(x\right)d\mu\left(x\right)\right)d\nu\left(y\right)$$
The one detail I'm missing is a reasoning as to why are $\varphi_{n},\varphi,\psi_{n},\psi$
  all measurable functions, I'd appreciate help closing this detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the formulation and proof of Fubini's Theorem (i.e., in W. Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis, p.140 Theorem 7.8.) If $f=f(x,y)\ge 0$ is integrable in the product space, then so are $\varphi$ and $\psi$.

Comment: I looked at the proof in Rudin's book and there is no specification there as to why $\varphi$ and $\psi$ as he defines them (and as I did) are measurable.

Comment: Look also the proof of Theorem 7.6.

Comment: If I understand correctly, from theorem 7.6 it is easy to obtain Fubini's Theorem for indicator functions and then from linearity extend it to simple functions. Which also implies that for simple functions the function defined by $\varphi_{n}:=\int\limits _{Y}\left(f_{n}\right)_{x}\left(y\right)d\nu\left(y\right)$ is measurable as a result of the iterated integrals existing. Thus measurability of $\varphi$ follows from it being a limit of measurable functions, am I correct?